# Unity + Niantic ARDK Aumeted Reality: Objects moving opposite to finger direction when camera is in front. need assistance drag and drop funcionality

Tags: unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop, augmented-reality

I'm working with Niantic's ARDK, and the company asked me to place three objects in the real world so that users can drag and drop them anywhere. I have successfully managed to place the objects, hold them, and drag them correctly when the camera is positioned behind the objects. However, there is a problem when the user positions their camera phone in front of the objects or on the left side, as the objects move in the opposite direction compared to the finger.

This is my code:

private void HeldObject(Touch touch)
{
Vector2 _touchPosition = touch.position;

```
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        if (hit.collider.tag == "apple")
        {
            dragObject = hit.transform;
            distanceToCamera = dragObject.position.z - Camera.main.transform.position.z;
            relativePositionTouch = new Vector3(_touchPosition.x, _touchPosition.y, distanceToCamera);
            relativePositionTouch = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(relativePositionTouch);
            cameraToObjectOffset = dragObject.position - relativePositionTouch;
            isHeld = true;
            Debug.Log($"Esta es la fase del touch: {touch.phase}");
        }
    }
}

private void MovedObjet(Touch touch)
{
    Vector2 _touchPosition = touch.position;
    relativePositionTouch = new Vector3(_touchPosition.x, _touchPosition.y, distanceToCamera);
    relativePositionTouch = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(relativePositionTouch);
    dragObject.position = relativePositionTouch + cameraToObjectOffset;
}
```

Thanks for your help

I tried to create a plane reference to use its position as a reference instead of relying on the camera position. This solved the problem of objects moving in the opposite direction. However, the objects now move away from the fingers instead of being dragged directly under them